# how to rank the items in chronological order in excel

Tags: ranking, ranking-functions

This is the list of score of 4 people.

jack     23
bob      25
lorty    45
sam      25

If i use rank.eq function then it gives rank lorty-1, bob-2, sam-2 and jack-4
is there any way the ranking can be made lorty-1, bob-2, sam-2 and jack-3

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *rank* players, `rank.eq` does what it has to do. Usually, you don't want Jack to be in different position if final score is

> jack 23, bob *25*, lorty 45, sam 25,

or if it's

> jack 23, bob *26*, lorty 45, sam 25.

It looks like there's nothing "*chronological*", anyway.